# How to pass multiple variables through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Below is a ajax code for a comment box which calls php code on another page that inserts comment into comments table. This code works well but it was just a test. Now I want to add userto, userfrom, postid along with comment into comments table For which I will need to pass variables of userto, userfrom etc from index.php to addcomment.php. Can I pass them through this ajax code to addcomments.php?

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".comment_button").click(function() {

        var test = $("#content").val();
        var dataString = 'content=' + test;

        if (test == '') {
            alert("Please Enter Some Text");
        } else {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" align="absmiddle"> <span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "addcomment.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $(".db").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('content').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('content').focus();
                    $("#flash").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

addcomment.php

```
if(isset($_POST['content'])) {
  $comment=strip_tags($_POST['content']);
  $com = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment) VALUES (:comment)");
  $com->execute(array(':comment'=>$comment)); 
}
```

Comment: If you want to send form data use `$('form').serialize()`, else use object as `data: { name: 'value', name2: 'value1' }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `dataString` variable can be a javascript object:

```
{ "data1" : "value1", "data2": "value2" }
```

Comment: thanks but how to get that on next page `if(isset($_POST['data1'])&& isset($_POST['data2')&&isset($_POST['data3']))
{`

Comment: `$data1 = $_POST['data1'];`